# Why does a PairFunction that extends an abstract class loses its field values when it's called?

Tags: java, apache-spark

How come when `NoParentFunction.call()` is called, it retains the field values whereas when `HasParentFunction().call()` is called, the field values are null/0?

```
public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("some.txt");

    textFile.mapToPair(new NoParentFunction(123, "blah")).collect();
    textFile.mapToPair(new HasParentFunction(123, "blah")).collect();
}

public class NoParentFunction implements PairFunction<String, String, String> {
  private int myInt;
  private String myString;

  public NoParentFunction(int myInt, String myString) {
    this.myInt = myInt;
    this.myString = myString;
  }

  public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("prints myInt correctly:" + myInt);
    return null;
  }
}

public class HasParentFunction extends AbstractFunction implements PairFunction<String, String, String> {

  public HasParentFunction(int myInt, String myString) {
    super(myInt, myString);
  }

  public Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("myInt: " + myInt + " is null");
    return null;
  }
}

public abstract class AbstractFunction {
  protected int myInt;
  protected String myString;

  public AbstractFunction(int myInt, String myString) {
    this.myInt = myInt;
    this.myString = myString;
  }

  abstract Tuple2<String, String> call(String s) throws Exception;
}
```

I can see why `HasParentFunction` loses its field values, due to `AbstractFunction`'s no-args constructor being called. But how come this does not happen in the class that ***does not*** extend the abstract class?

Comment: I believe you will need to make `AbstractFunction` serializable.

Comment: @msandiford You're right. Can you explain why adding `implements Serializable' resolves the issue?

Comment: Spark needs it's `PairFunction` objects to be serializable in order to send the "work" to the workers on the network, and the `PairFunction` interface extends the `Serializable` interface to facilitate this.  So in your case the `HasParentFunction` class implements `Serializable` due to implementing the `PairFunction` interface, but the `AbstractFunction` class does not.  It's not clear to me why you don't get exceptions from the Java runtime when trying to serialize a `HasParentFunction` because of this.